# My Neural Network algorithm is not working mnist numbers

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, backpropagation

I could use a second set of eyes on my neural network.

This is the mnist number recognition project.

I'm not sure where the issue is.

I previously implemented the ai with tensor flow successfully. 
I'm not looking to use an api as a solution.

I would appreciate any help anyone can give.

Here's the project on github, it's only an init file and then the neural_network.

https://github.com/nealchawn/ai_trial_2

```
class NeuralNetwork(object):
def __init__(self, sizes):
    self.activations = []
    self.outputs = []
    self.weights = []
    self.biases = []

    self.sizes = sizes
    self.set_random_weights()
    self.set_random_biases()

def set_random_weights(self):
    for layer_index, layer_size in enumerate(self.sizes[1:], start=1):
        layer_weights = []
        for size in range(layer_size):
            for size in range(self.sizes[layer_index-1]):
                layer_weights.append(random.uniform(-5.0, 5.0))
        self.weights.append(layer_weights)

def set_random_biases(self):
    total_biases = 0
    # add extra zero bias to help future indexing
    #self.biases.append(0)
    for index, size in enumerate(self.sizes[0:-1], start=1):
        total_biases += 1
    for x in range(total_biases):
        self.biases.append(random.uniform(-5.0, 5.0))

def train_network(self, training_data, training_labels):
    if len(training_data) != len(training_labels):
        print("Error data and labels must be the same length")
    data = list(zip(training_data, training_labels))
    self.sgd(data)

def sgd(self, data, mini_batch_size = 1000):
    # first we'll create batches of training data

    n = len(data)
    data_batches = [
        data[k:k + mini_batch_size]
        for k in range(0, n, mini_batch_size)
    ]
    print(len(data_batches))
    i = 0
    for mini_batch in data_batches:
        print("Batch: " + str(i))
        i += 1
        self.update_mini_batch(mini_batch)
        self.network_outputs()

    print("Finished All training data!")

def update_mini_batch(self, mini_data_batch):
    weight_gradients = []
    bias_gradients = []
    i = 0
    for training_input in mini_data_batch:
        training_object, training_label = training_input

        self.feedforward(training_object)

        weights_gradient, bias_gradient = self.backpropogation(training_label)

        weight_gradients.append(weights_gradient)
        bias_gradients.append(bias_gradient)

    # average gradients

    weights_gradient = np.average(weight_gradients,axis=0)
    biases_gradient = np.average(bias_gradients, axis=0)
    # may need to convert to list

    weights_gradient_list = []
    for weight_gradient in weights_gradient:
        weights_gradient_list.append(weight_gradient.tolist())

    #weights_gradient = weights_gradient.tolist()
    biases_gradient = biases_gradient.tolist()

    for x in range(len(self.biases)):
        self.biases[x] -= 0.1*biases_gradient[x]

    weight_gradient_index = 0
    for layer_index, layer_weights in enumerate(self.weights, start=0):
        for weight_index, weight in enumerate(layer_weights):
            self.weights[layer_index][weight_index] = weight - 0.1*weights_gradient_list[layer_index][weight_index]
            weight_gradient_index += 1


def feedforward(self, training_object):
    # set inputs
    self.outputs = []
    self.activations = []

    temp_activations = []
    for index in range(self.sizes[0]):
        temp_activations.append(training_object[index])
    self.activations.append(temp_activations)

    for layer_index, layer_size in enumerate(self.sizes[1:], start=0):
        layer_weights = self.weights[layer_index]
        layer_inputs = self.activations[layer_index]
        weight_index = 0

        layer_outputs = []
        layer_activations = []

        for node_index in range(layer_size):
            node_weights = []
            # get node weights
            #print(f"layer size: {layer_size}, previous_layer_size: {self.sizes[layer_index]}, layer weights: {len(layer_weights)}")
            for x in range(self.sizes[layer_index]):
                node_weights.append(layer_weights[weight_index])
                weight_index += 1
            output = 0
            for indx in range(len(node_weights)):
                output += layer_inputs[indx]*node_weights[indx]
            output = output + self.biases[layer_index]
            layer_outputs.append(output)
            layer_activations.append(self.sigmoid(output))
        self.outputs.append(layer_outputs)
        self.activations.append(layer_activations)

def backpropogation(self, training_label):
    costs = []
    output_layer_activations = self.activations[-1]
    output_layer_outputs = self.outputs[-1]

    correct_labels = self.translate_label_to_array(training_label)

    costs.append(self.compute_cost_derivative(correct_labels, output_layer_activations))
    for cost_index, cost in enumerate(costs[0]):
        costs[0][cost_index] = cost*self.sigmoid_prime(output_layer_outputs[cost_index])

    # calculate costs for layers
    for layer_index, layer_size in enumerate(self.sizes[::-1][1:-1], start=1):
        layer_costs = []
        layer_weights = self.weights[-layer_index]
        layer_outputs = self.outputs[-(layer_index+1)]
        previous_layer_costs = costs[layer_index-1]

        next_layer_size = self.sizes[::-1][1:][layer_index]

        layer_weights_formatted = []
        for x in range(layer_size):
            layer_weights_formatted.append([])
        for weight_index, weight in enumerate(layer_weights, start=0):
            #print(f"weight index:{weight_index % next_layer_size} layer_index: {weight_index}")
            layer_weights_formatted[weight_index%layer_size].append(layer_weights[weight_index])

        #print(f"next_layer_size:{layer_size} costs: {len(previous_layer_costs)}, layer_weights_formatted: {layer_weights_formatted}")
        for x in range(layer_size):
            node_cost = 0
            for y, cost in enumerate(previous_layer_costs,start=0):
                node_cost += layer_weights_formatted[x][y]*cost
            layer_costs.append(node_cost)

        # layer_costs same order as next layer's activations
        for cost_index, cost in enumerate(layer_costs):
            layer_costs[cost_index] = cost * self.sigmoid_prime(layer_outputs[cost_index])

        costs.append(layer_costs)
    # calculate weight errors
    weight_errors = []
    bias_errors = []
    for layer_index, layer_costs in enumerate(costs[::-1]):
        layer_activations = self.activations[layer_index]
        layer_weight_errors = []
        for cost_index, cost in enumerate(layer_costs,start=0):
            for activation in layer_activations:
                layer_weight_errors.append(activation * cost)
        weight_errors.append(np.array(layer_weight_errors))
        bias_errors.append(sum(layer_costs))

    return weight_errors, bias_errors

# conversion tool
def translate_label_to_array(self, y):
    translated_label = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    translated_label[y] = 1
    return np.array(translated_label)

# output tools

def network_outputs(self):
    print("Output layer: ")
    for x in range(self.sizes[-1]):
        print("node " + str(x) + ": " + str(self.activations[-1][x]))

def total_activations(self):
    print(len(self.activations))

def compute_cost_derivative(self, y, output_activations):
    """Return the vector of partial derivatives \partial C_x /
    \partial a for the output activations."""
    return (output_activations - y)

def sigmoid(self, z):
    """"The sigmoid function."""
    return (1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-z)))

def sigmoid_prime(self, z):
    return (self.sigmoid(z) * (1 - self.sigmoid(z)))
```

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: okay, thanks, ill read it over, in the meantime i just included a code sample and removed a lot of exposition.